# Is ReferenceEquals - true and Equals - false expected behaviour?

Tags: c#

If `object.ReferenceEquals` returns true, should `instance.Equals` always return true?

Would you think its unexpected behaviour where the output below was pass/fail?

```
Assert.True(object.ReferenceEquals(obj,obj));
Assert.True(obj.Equals(obj));
```

Personally I think its strange, and cant really think of a *good* reason, where an instance should not be equal to itself.

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  The reverse is not always true.

Comment: What part is unclear? I know the reverse is not always true, but the obverse should always be true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways to answer your question.

- It's unexpected behavior, yes. A properly-designed class should always return true from `.Equals` if it returns true from `.ReferenceEquals`. That's codified in MSDN's *Design Guidelines for Developing Class Libraries*, *[Implementing the Equals Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336aedhh.aspx)* article:

  > Follow the contract defined on the Object.Equals Method as follows:
  >        `x.Equals(x)` returns true.
- But that requirement is not enforced by the language or runtime. The designer of the class in question is perfectly free to define `Equals` as `{ return false; }`. Perverse, but possible.

Comment: I don't know why the other answer (it has been removed) got downvoted as it said the same as this one. It's awkward, but possible. We would need to know that object's class to understand it better. +1 anyway

Comment: The owner deleted it, @Andre.

Comment: Indeed, but someone downvoted it, and I disagree. Anyway, your answer is more complete.

Comment: Excellent, URL says it all really. Took me ages to track that bug down :(

Comment: Yeah, it's like trying to frame a house when the foundation is sinking. You need to depend on certain invariants, and when you can't, everything goes to heck.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if reference equals is true, proper implementation of equals should return true.

Comment: Strictly speaking, no.  If Equals is overridden to do something stupid  ie. force an inequality, the .Equals might not return true even if they are the same instance.

Comment: @StefanH - I meant the equals implementation *should* be, not *would* be returning true.